# How do I do an exact whois search?

Tags: ubuntu, spam, whois

When I execute the following whois command on my Ubuntu server, I get all sorts of other domains which contain google.com in the name, but clearly aren't owned by google.  As this appears to be some sort of spam, I won't paste the output here.  I'd like to check for exactly the name I typed in.  I thought the following would work, but it doesn't.  What is the proper way to do an exact match?

```
whois -Hx google.com
```

Update: I found a work around by using a Ruby whois script: http://www.ruby-whois.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "spam" you're seeing is the COM registry whois server finding partial matches on host (nameserver) entries as well as domain names.

`whois 'domain google.com'` will avoid all the host record matches by limiting the results to domain objects only.

This isn't a client setting, but a whois server function.

`whois -h whois.internic.net help` for more details